# How can I gather unique objects from models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have model "show" which has_many "performances" and a performance has a certain "location".
Two or more performances may have the same location.

I'm looking for a way to get all the locations used by the show's performances, but only once (if there are three performances with location X, I need to get X only once).

Edit: I'm now at this form: an array of objects `[[performance_id:1, location_id:1],[performance_id:2, location_id:1],[performance_id:3, location_id:2]]` . How can I get an array containing [1,2] (the unique location_id) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added commas to the array:

```
[
  [performance_id:1, location_id:1],
  [performance_id:2, location_id:1],
  [performance_id:3, location_id:2]  ].flatten.map {|h| h[:location_id]}.uniq

 => [1, 2]
```

Comment: In Ruby 1.9 `uniq` can take a block, so this could just be `...flatten.uniq { |h| h[:location_id] }`, without the `map`.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this will do it for you

```
show.performances.collect(&:location).uniq
```

Comment: I'm now at this form: an array of objects [[performance_id:1, location_id:1][performance_id:2, location_id:1][performance_id:3, location_id:2]] . How can I get an array containing [1,2] (the unique location_id) ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like

```
Location.joins(:performances).where(:performances => { :show_id => 5 }).group("locations.id")
```

Comment: I'm now at this form: an array of objects [[performance_id:1, location_id:1][performance_id:2, location_id:1][performance_id:3, location_id:2]] . How can I get an array containing [1,2] (the unique location_id)